# How to move django lib folder

Tags: django, move

I have installed django and by default it is in /usr/share/pyshared folder. What I would like to do is to copy the django folder to for example /opt/ folder and use the django from there.

How can I do this? Thx for any tips :)

best regards

Answer (score 2):

You can put Django or any other python package wherever you like, as long as that directory is on the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. However, it's generally not a good idea to put packages in various places. They should either go in your site-packages/dist-packages (or in your case, apparently pyshared) directory or in a virtualenv (which still uses it's own centralized site-packages directory).